# composer install messenger generating erros on clearing the cache

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-messenger

trying to install symfony/messenger.

The script seems to be generating an error message when trying to install it, it goes thru the components is installed, issues start once the composer is launching `Executing script cache:clear`
:

```
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update symfony/messenger
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating optimized autoload files
78 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.

Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!  
!!  In ArrayNode.php line 322:
!!                                                                                 
!!    Unrecognized option "reset_on_message" under "framework.messenger". Availab  
!!    le options are "buses", "default_bus", "enabled", "failure_transport", "rou  
!!    ting", "serializer", "transports".                                           
!!                                                                                 
!!  
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
```

Comment: What's your symfony version and have you changed the default messenger config? `reset_on_message` was introduced in v5.4 of the framework.

Comment: @msg ` symfony -V` output : `Symfony CLI version v4.28.1 `.

Comment: That's the version of `symfony-cli`, not necessarily the framework, run `composer info symfony/framwework-bundle` and look for the `version` line. Or run `bin/console -V`.

Comment: @msg  `symfony/framework-bundle": "5.3.*"` from composer.json

Comment: Ok, there you go. You have a version that doesn't support that configuration parameter. Have you changed the config yourself or does it come straight from the recipe? (assuming you are using flex). Since 5.3 is not supported anymore I'd just update to 5.4.

Comment: alright thanks yeah used the flex recipe i guess  since im using symfony flex, i didnt do any configuration just launched the install script